# Error Class (FluentValidation) fails to install

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, fluentvalidation

i'm working on a .net c# project that requires FluentValidation package, but when i try installing it, it gives this error

[image]

i am new to C# and the guide i am using did not cover this issue, it assumes you know or can setup this package. i really need assistance to forge ahead.

else i keep having these underlined errors from the classes and methods that rely on the package as shown in the image below.

[image]

i'd be glad if anyone can assist me, thanks.

Comment: This seems to be known issues. Take a look here: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/711 Which version of .NET Standard are you using?

Comment: im using .Net framework version 4.7.03

Comment: Try installing the v.2.0.3 package: `Install-Package NETStandard.Library -Version 2.0.3` Then restart VS, rebuild and write if the problem persists.